# Did I brick my pogoplug?

Tags: networking, diagnostic

I just received a POGO-P21 and followed the [archlinux installation instructions](http://archlinuxarm.org/platforms/armv6/pogoplug-provideov3).  Got to step 12 without any trouble or error message.  Rebooted the device, and now it won't come up.

Good news:

- When I power cycle the Pogoplug, the light stays off, then blinks green, then goes to steady green.
- If I `clear ip dhcp binding 192.168.1.121` (the old IP), it immediately grabs a new IP from the router's DHCP server.

Bad news:

- I can't ping or ssh in to the Pogoplug.

Anyone have any hints for diagnosing this thing, either on the network side to see if somehow it just has ping and ssh turned off, or on the Archlinux side?

Comment: Have you tried to bring up a serial or netconsole connection?

Comment: What happens if you nmap its IP address?

Comment: What happens when you try to ssh into the new IP?